# Datastore GQL: Distinct + Count query

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Google Datastore table on this format:

```
"KEY","Country","PersonName"
"1","USA","Joe"
"2","USA","Dan"
"3","Canada","Willo"
```

I want to count how many registered people I have on each country. A combination between count aggregation and distinct.

Expected output:

```
"USA", 2
"Canada", 1
```

The solution I'm looking for based on GQL.

Thanks for help.

Comment: How this table looks on GCP datastore? Can you share screenshot of your `datastore` ?

Comment: Hey @RoopaM, can't share screenshot. The table looks like mentioned on the first code block.

Comment: Can you share how you added above database? Because, as of my knowledge we can't create USA twice as property name should be unique.

Comment: @RoopaM Sorry for confusion. Added the `KEY` column.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will require multiple queries.

The first one is to get the list of Countries[1], and then another one to get count for a country[2].

```
[1] SELECT DISTINCT ON (Country) Country FROM Test

[2] AGGREGATE COUNT(*) OVER (SELECT * FROM Test WHERE Country="USA")
```

This I believe is due to the Datastore limitations, as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#grouping).

Please note "Test" is my Google Datastore table ("Kind") name here.